# QGIS - Geometry type Line String: Size fluctuates when zooming, - don't want it to

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, geometry

Here are two pictures. One zoomed out. I don't want the size of this black X to change when it's zoomed out. Any suggestions?

[image]
[[image]

Comment: Images look similar, have you perhaps uploaded the same image  twice?

Answer (score 5):

Select `Meters at Scale` or `Map Units` next to the stroke width

[image]

[image]

[image]